# Python CSV module - quotes go missing

Tags: python, csv, double-quotes

I have a CSV file that has data like this

```
15,"I",2,41301888,"BYRNESS RAW","","BYRNESS VILLAGE","NORTHUMBERLAND","ENG"
11,"I",3,41350101,2,2935,2,2008-01-09,1,8,0,2003-02-01,,2009-12-22,2003-02-11,377016.00,601912.00,377105.00,602354.00,10
```

I am reading this and then writing different rows to different CSV files.

However, in the original data there are quotes around the non-numeric fields, as some of them contain commas within the field.

I am not able to keep the quotes.

I have researched lots and discovered the `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` however this now results in a quote mark around every field and I dont know why??

If i try one of the other quoting options like MINIMAL I end up with an error message regarding the date value, 2008-01-09, not being a float.

I have tried to create a dialect, add the quoting on the csv reader and writer but nothing I have tried results in the getting an exact match to the original data.

Anyone had this same problem and found a solution.

Comment: The quoting in the source is inconsistent to begin with.

Comment: In the source there are quotes just around the non-numeric as I described. This is consistent

Comment: Dates are not numeric. And nothing is numeric once you read it in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When writing, `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` keeps values unquoted as long as they're *numbers*, ie. if their type is `int` or `float` (for example), which means it will write what you expect.

Your problem could be that, when reading, a `csv.reader` will turn every row it reads into a `list` of *strings* (if you read the documentation carefully enough, you'll see a reader does *not* perform automatic data type conversion!

If you don't perform any kind of conversion **after reading**, then when you write you'll end up with everything on quotes... because everything you write is a string.

Edit: of course, date fields will be quoted, because they are *not* numbers, meaning you cannot get the exact expected behaviour using the standard `csv.writer`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have a problem? The behavior you're describing is correct: The `csv` module will enclose strings in quotes *only if it's necessary* for parsing them correctly. So you should expect to see quotes only around strings containing a comma, newlines, etc. Unless you're getting errors reading your output back in, there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get an "exact match" of the original data is a difficult and potentially fruitless endeavor.  `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` put quotes around everything because every field was a string when you read it in.

Your concern that some of the "quoted" input fields could have commas is usually not that big a deal.  If you added a comma to one of your quoted fields and used the default writer, the field with the comma would be automatically quoted in the output.