# Read a CSV file and put double quotes around data items

Tags: python, csv

Here is my data:

> ID,application_id,award_notice_date,budget_start,budget_end,core_project_num,ed_inst_type
>   1,3000011,7/1/1985,6/30/1986,A03AH000859,SCHOOLS OF PUBLIC HEALTH
>   2,3000012,7/1/1985,6/30/1986,A03AH000860,SCHOOLS OF PUBLIC HEALTH
>   3,3000013,7/1/1985,6/30/1986,A03AH000861,SCHOOLS OF PUBLIC HEALTH

What I want is:

> "ID","application_id","budget_start","budget_end","core_project_num","ed_inst_type"
>   1,3000011,"7/1/1985","6/30/1986","A03AH000859","SCHOOLS OF PUBLIC HEALTH"
>   2,3000012,"7/1/1985","6/30/1986","A03AH000860","SCHOOLS OF PUBLIC HEALTH"
>   3,3000013,"7/1/1985","6/30/1986","A03AH000861","SCHOOLS OF PUBLIC HEALTH"

Here is my code:

```
import csv

import sys


input_file = str(sys.argv[1])

output_file = str(sys.argv[2])


ifile  = open(input_file)

reader = csv.reader(ifile)

ofile  = open(output_file, 'w')

writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

for row in reader:

       writer.writerow(row)
```

The issue:
Add double quotes for all data (including both numeric and non-numeric data)

> "ID","application_id","budget_start","budget_end","core_project_num","ed_inst_type"
>   "1","3000011","7/1/1985","6/30/1986","A03AH000859","SCHOOLS OF PUBLIC HEALTH"
>   "2","3000012","7/1/1985","6/30/1986","A03AH000860","SCHOOLS OF PUBLIC HEALTH"
>   "3","3000013","7/1/1985","6/30/1986","","A03AH000861","SCHOOLS OF PUBLIC HEALTH"

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/9354366/5818240. Make sure your numeric data are not read as strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python CSV module - quotes go missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353792/python-csv-module-quotes-go-missing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the integer fields to integer values with something like this:

```
for row in reader:
    row = [int(x) if re.match(r'-?\d+$', x) else x for x in row]
    writer.writerow(row)
```

just add

```
import re
```

at the beginning of your program.